# Multiple drives fail in Dell R730xd when partitioned

Tags: dell, raid10

I have a used (new to me) Dell R730xd running 2 virtual disks. The first consists of 2x 600GB drives in RAID 1 and the second consists of 10x 6TB drives in RAID 10. The first virtual drive works fine and has no problems. The second one causes multiple physical drive failures whenever I try to partition it.

So far I have tried rebuilding the virtual drive, overwriting the physical drives, clearing the physical drives, deleting and rebuilding the virtual drive with quick and full initialization, all resulting in the same outcome of multiple random physical drives failing immediately on partitioning.

[image: Failed physical drives]

[image: Failed physical drive detail]

[image: Virtual drives]

**Update 1:**

I have replaced the raid controller and it is doing the same thing. Multiple drives fail as soon as I try to "initialize with gpt" in Proxmox. Really anything that involves writing to the drives. There has been no pattern as to which drive(s) will fail and at this point drives in every single slot have failed.

The BIOS and RAID controller firmware are the latest versions.

Have tried different block sizes, different RAID configurations (5, 10, 60) and still nothing. While I always appreciate a good downvote without explanation, it would be helpful if anyone had questions to clarify if I am missing any information or if this is posted in the wrong place.

**Update 2**

Power supplies should be sufficient. I tried another test to see if running a smaller number of drives an array would work. I created 2 new virtual disks and put 4 physical disks in one and 6 in the other and set up both for RAID 10. Ran full initialization on both of them. Within seconds of partitioning the 6 drive array, 3 drives went into a failure state and when I tried the same on the 4 drive array, 1 went into failure state.

Output from `megacli -pdlist -a0`

```
Adapter #0

Enclosure Device ID: 32
Slot Number: 0
Drive's position: DiskGroup: 0, Span: 0, Arm: 0
Enclosure position: 1
Device Id: 0
WWN: 5000CCA01828F9E3
Sequence Number: 2
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SAS

Raw Size: 558.911 GB [0x45dd2fb0 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 558.411 GB [0x45cd2fb0 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 558.375 GB [0x45cc0000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  512
Logical Sector Size:  512
Physical Sector Size:  512
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: NA02
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x5000cca01828f9e1
SAS Address(1): 0x0
Connected Port Number: 0(path0) 
Inquiry Data: NETAPP  X412_HVIPC560A15NA02JZVRJLJM            
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive:  Not Certified
Drive Temperature :38C (100.40 F)
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s 
Port-1 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No



Enclosure Device ID: 32
Slot Number: 1
Drive's position: DiskGroup: 0, Span: 0, Arm: 1
Enclosure position: 1
Device Id: 1
WWN: 5000CCA02A4561D7
Sequence Number: 2
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SAS

Raw Size: 558.911 GB [0x45dd2fb0 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 558.411 GB [0x45cd2fb0 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 558.375 GB [0x45cc0000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  512
Logical Sector Size:  512
Physical Sector Size:  512
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: NA04
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x5000cca02a4561d5
SAS Address(1): 0x0
Connected Port Number: 0(path0) 
Inquiry Data: NETAPP  X412_HVIPC560A15NA04LXW74WLM            
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive:  Not Certified
Drive Temperature :39C (102.20 F)
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s 
Port-1 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No



Enclosure Device ID: 32
Slot Number: 2
Drive's position: DiskGroup: 1, Span: 0, Arm: 0
Enclosure position: 1
Device Id: 2
WWN: 5000C50085461B30
Sequence Number: 4
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SAS

Raw Size: 5.458 TB [0x2baa0f4b0 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 5.457 TB [0x2ba90f4b0 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 5.457 TB [0x2ba900000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  512
Logical Sector Size:  512
Physical Sector Size:  4096
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: NE03
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x5000c50085461b31
SAS Address(1): 0x0
Connected Port Number: 0(path0) 
Inquiry Data: SEAGATE ST6000NM0034    NE03Z4D4BL0N            
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 12.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 12.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive:  Not Certified
Drive Temperature :38C (100.40 F)
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  Yes 
PI: PI with type 2
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 12.0Gb/s 
Port-1 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 12.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No



Enclosure Device ID: 32
Slot Number: 3
Drive's position: DiskGroup: 1, Span: 0, Arm: 1
Enclosure position: 1
Device Id: 3
WWN: 5000C500856F44F4
Sequence Number: 6
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 7
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SAS

Raw Size: 5.458 TB [0x2baa0f4b0 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 5.457 TB [0x2ba90f4b0 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 5.457 TB [0x2ba900000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  512
Logical Sector Size:  512
Physical Sector Size:  4096
Firmware state: Failed
Device Firmware Level: 7FA6
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x5000c500856f44f5
SAS Address(1): 0x0
Connected Port Number: 0(path0) 
Inquiry Data: SEAGATE DKS2F-H6R0SS    7FA6Z4D4HCAZ            
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 12.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 12.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive:  Not Certified
Drive Temperature :39C (102.20 F)
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 12.0Gb/s 
Port-1 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 12.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No



Enclosure Device ID: 32
Slot Number: 4
Drive's position: DiskGroup: 1, Span: 0, Arm: 2
Enclosure position: 1
Device Id: 4
WWN: 5000C500856F7048
Sequence Number: 5
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 7
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SAS

Raw Size: 5.458 TB [0x2baa0f4b0 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 5.457 TB [0x2ba90f4b0 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 5.457 TB [0x2ba900000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  512
Logical Sector Size:  512
Physical Sector Size:  4096
Firmware state: Failed
Device Firmware Level: 7FA6
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x5000c500856f7049
SAS Address(1): 0x0
Connected Port Number: 0(path0) 
Inquiry Data: SEAGATE DKS2F-H6R0SS    7FA6Z4D4HKJV            
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 12.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 12.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive:  Not Certified
Drive Temperature :41C (105.80 F)
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 12.0Gb/s 
Port-1 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 12.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No



Enclosure Device ID: 32
Slot Number: 5
Drive's position: DiskGroup: 1, Span: 0, Arm: 3
Enclosure position: 1
Device Id: 5
WWN: 5000C500856F5378
Sequence Number: 5
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 7
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SAS

Raw Size: 5.458 TB [0x2baa0f4b0 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 5.457 TB [0x2ba90f4b0 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 5.457 TB [0x2ba900000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  512
Logical Sector Size:  512
Physical Sector Size:  4096
Firmware state: Failed
Device Firmware Level: 7FA6
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x5000c500856f5379
SAS Address(1): 0x0
Connected Port Number: 0(path0) 
Inquiry Data: SEAGATE DKS2F-H6R0SS    7FA6Z4D4HBXM            
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 12.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 12.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive:  Not Certified
Drive Temperature :39C (102.20 F)
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 12.0Gb/s 
Port-1 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 12.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No



Enclosure Device ID: 32
Slot Number: 6
Drive's position: DiskGroup: 2, Span: 0, Arm: 0
Enclosure position: 1
Device Id: 6
WWN: 5000C500864616E0
Sequence Number: 4
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SAS

Raw Size: 5.458 TB [0x2baa0f4b0 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 5.457 TB [0x2ba90f4b0 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 5.457 TB [0x2ba900000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  512
Logical Sector Size:  512
Physical Sector Size:  4096
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: E0B1
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x5000c500864616e1
SAS Address(1): 0x0
Connected Port Number: 0(path0) 
Inquiry Data: SEAGATE ST6000NM0034    E0B1Z4D4V84C            
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 12.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 12.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive:  Not Certified
Drive Temperature :40C (104.00 F)
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 12.0Gb/s 
Port-1 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 12.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No



Enclosure Device ID: 32
Slot Number: 7
Drive's position: DiskGroup: 2, Span: 0, Arm: 1
Enclosure position: 1
Device Id: 7
WWN: 5000C50097C3CFDC
Sequence Number: 4
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SAS

Raw Size: 5.458 TB [0x2baa0f4b0 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 5.457 TB [0x2ba90f4b0 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 5.457 TB [0x2ba900000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  512
Logical Sector Size:  512
Physical Sector Size:  4096
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: MS2D
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x5000c50097c3cfdd
SAS Address(1): 0x0
Connected Port Number: 0(path0) 
Inquiry Data: SEAGATE ST6000NM0034    MS2DS4D0ZZZ2            
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 6.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive Temperature :41C (105.80 F)
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s 
Port-1 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No



Enclosure Device ID: 32
Slot Number: 8
Drive's position: DiskGroup: 2, Span: 0, Arm: 2
Enclosure position: 1
Device Id: 8
WWN: 5000C500856F26E8
Sequence Number: 4
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SAS

Raw Size: 5.458 TB [0x2baa0f4b0 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 5.457 TB [0x2ba90f4b0 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 5.457 TB [0x2ba900000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  512
Logical Sector Size:  512
Physical Sector Size:  4096
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: 7FA6
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x5000c500856f26e9
SAS Address(1): 0x0
Connected Port Number: 0(path0) 
Inquiry Data: SEAGATE DKS2F-H6R0SS    7FA6Z4D4HKS2            
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 12.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 12.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive:  Not Certified
Drive Temperature :39C (102.20 F)
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 12.0Gb/s 
Port-1 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 12.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No



Enclosure Device ID: 32
Slot Number: 9
Drive's position: DiskGroup: 2, Span: 0, Arm: 3
Enclosure position: 1
Device Id: 9
WWN: 5000C500856F57E8
Sequence Number: 4
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SAS

Raw Size: 5.458 TB [0x2baa0f4b0 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 5.457 TB [0x2ba90f4b0 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 5.457 TB [0x2ba900000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  512
Logical Sector Size:  512
Physical Sector Size:  4096
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: 7FA6
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x5000c500856f57e9
SAS Address(1): 0x0
Connected Port Number: 0(path0) 
Inquiry Data: SEAGATE DKS2F-H6R0SS    7FA6Z4D4HKL0            
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 12.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 12.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive:  Not Certified
Drive Temperature :41C (105.80 F)
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 12.0Gb/s 
Port-1 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 12.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No



Enclosure Device ID: 32
Slot Number: 10
Drive's position: DiskGroup: 2, Span: 0, Arm: 4
Enclosure position: 1
Device Id: 10
WWN: 5000C500856F5384
Sequence Number: 6
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 7
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SAS

Raw Size: 5.458 TB [0x2baa0f4b0 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 5.457 TB [0x2ba90f4b0 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 5.457 TB [0x2ba900000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  512
Logical Sector Size:  512
Physical Sector Size:  4096
Firmware state: Failed
Device Firmware Level: 7FA6
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x5000c500856f5385
SAS Address(1): 0x0
Connected Port Number: 0(path0) 
Inquiry Data: SEAGATE DKS2F-H6R0SS    7FA6Z4D4HBXE            
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 12.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 12.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive:  Not Certified
Drive Temperature :44C (111.20 F)
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 12.0Gb/s 
Port-1 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 12.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No



Enclosure Device ID: 32
Slot Number: 11
Drive's position: DiskGroup: 2, Span: 0, Arm: 5
Enclosure position: 1
Device Id: 11
WWN: 5000C50084938704
Sequence Number: 4
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SAS

Raw Size: 5.458 TB [0x2baa0f4b0 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 5.457 TB [0x2ba90f4b0 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 5.457 TB [0x2ba900000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  512
Logical Sector Size:  512
Physical Sector Size:  4096
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: E0B1
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x5000c50084938705
SAS Address(1): 0x0
Connected Port Number: 0(path0) 
Inquiry Data: SEAGATE ST6000NM0034    E0B1Z4D3GAJ4            
FDE Capable: Not Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None 
Device Speed: 12.0Gb/s 
Link Speed: 12.0Gb/s 
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive:  Not Certified
Drive Temperature :41C (105.80 F)
PI Eligibility:  No 
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 12.0Gb/s 
Port-1 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 12.0Gb/s 
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No




Exit Code: 0x00
```

And the output of smartctl --all /dev/sdc -d megaraid,3

```
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.15.102-1-pve] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               SEAGATE
Product:              DKS2F-H6R0SS
Revision:             7FA6
Compliance:           SPC-3
User Capacity:        6,001,175,126,016 bytes [6.00 TB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Physical block size:  4096 bytes
LU is fully provisioned
Rotation Rate:        7200 rpm
Form Factor:          3.5 inches
Logical Unit id:      0x5000c500856f44f7
Serial number:        Z4D4HCAZ0000R642M38L
Device type:          disk
Transport protocol:   SAS (SPL-3)
Local Time is:        Sat Jun 24 15:47:16 2023 EDT
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is:     Enabled
Temperature Warning:  Disabled or Not Supported

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Health Status: OK

Grown defects during certification = 0
Total blocks reassigned during format = 0
Total new blocks reassigned = 0
Power on minutes since format = 2930556
Current Drive Temperature:     39 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        68 C

Accumulated power on time, hours:minutes 49036:01
Manufactured in week 20 of year 2016
Specified cycle count over device lifetime:  10000
Accumulated start-stop cycles:  287
Specified load-unload count over device lifetime:  300000
Accumulated load-unload cycles:  2313
Elements in grown defect list: 0

Vendor (Seagate Cache) information
  Blocks sent to initiator = 2839836544
  Blocks received from initiator = 3640828640
  Blocks read from cache and sent to initiator = 3518
  Number of read and write commands whose size <= segment size = 5252389
  Number of read and write commands whose size > segment size = 0

Vendor (Seagate/Hitachi) factory information
  number of hours powered up = 49036.02
  number of minutes until next internal SMART test = 36

Error counter log:
           Errors Corrected by           Total   Correction     Gigabytes    Total
               ECC          rereads/    errors   algorithm      processed    uncorrected
           fast | delayed   rewrites  corrected  invocations   [10^9 bytes]  errors
read:    7613600        0         0   7613600          0       2081.725           0
write:         0        0         0         0          0       6266.395           0
verify: 2930355543        0         0  2930355543          0       6001.367           0

Non-medium error count:        0


[GLTSD (Global Logging Target Save Disable) set. Enable Save with '-S on']
SMART Self-test log
Num  Test              Status                 segment  LifeTime  LBA_first_err [SK ASC ASQ]
     Description                              number   (hours)
# 1  Background short  Completed                   -   48763                 - [-   -    -]

Long (extended) Self-test duration: 5 seconds [0.1 minutes]
```

Power status screen covering the last hour when I attempted drive formatting:

[image]

Should also mention that the formatting attempts causing the failures have been done through the Proxmox "Initialize Disk with GPT" tool. I have also tried formatting with gparted and fdisk with the same results.

[image]

**Update 3**

I tried replacing all 10 drives in the array that keeps failing with Dell drives instead of Seagate. Same size and RPM. Built a RAID 10 array and during fast initialization the first drive in the array failed. Deleted the virtual drive, swapped out the drive the failed with another, built another RAID 10 array and on fast init that drive failed as well.

This makes me think something is wrong with the backplane... Will be pursuing that next and will update here when that is done.

**Update 4**

After installing the new drives, I physically removed 6 of them and tried forming a RAID10 array on the 4 remaining (including one in the slot that kept failing). This worked and seemed to indicate there was a power issue in the backplane. To confirm, I tried forming a RAID10 array with all 10 drives and instead of the expected failure, it worked. Set up Proxmox, and started doing as much read/write as I could and so far, everything has held up. Now I am very confused. Don't want to complain that something is working, but absolutely did not expect the drives to initialize successfully. Wondering if maybe I missed deleting a foreign configuration or something the first time I tried installing all 10 of them.

Would really like to know what was actually going on.

Comment: Is the power supply sufficient to run all drives simultaneously? Check also the backplane for problems. What smartctl says about these drives? `smartctl` **can** query SMART status of drives behind PERC (LSI MegaRAID), you have to use something like `smartctl --all /dev/sda -d megaraid,N` where N is megaraid-internal physical "Device Id" as reported by `megacli -pdlist -a0`.

Comment: Thanks @NikitaKipriyanov the results of those commands are posted in update 2 in my question. I ran smartctl on one of the failed drives, please let me know if it would help to see any of the others. Thanks again!

Comment: open a support case on the vendor, Dell has a very impressive one